# 2007 Ford Territory headlight/taillights issue

Tags: electrical, ford, headlight, tail-lights

Recently my 2007 Ford Territory's battery went dead. One week ago I had to be jump started.  It was fine turning the ignition on throughout the next few days. The dash lights began intermittently turning off. All that I needed to do was to turn the headlights off and back on again and the dash light would illuminate. 
Knowing that my battery was on its way out I had it replaced.

Since then, I have no park lights (both forward and rear) and no tail lights when low beam headlights on.

**Works**

Low beams headlight (forward)

High beams both forward and rearward 
Brake lights

**Does not work**

Park lights both forward and rearward

Tail light when low beam on

**Variables**

When park lights turned to on position (one click) and high beam activated the park light globe DOES work. (Forward) and rear taillight.
(ALL globes are fine)

---

***What could be the issue where changing the battery could cause this?***

***Could it be another system and unrelated the battery change?***